# How do I force download of a file through Flysystem?

Tags: php, yii2, flysystem

I may be missing something exceptionally obvious here, but I'm using yii2-flysystem along with Dropbox to read and write files.

I can upload and write them to Dropbox with no problem but then, when reading like this:

```
$file = Yii::$app->dropboxFs->read($fn);
```

..all that gives me is a string (/tmp/phpQkg8mJ).

How do I actually force the download of the file that I'm reading? I'm not sure what that temporary file location actually relates to.

Comment: is thar a 3rd party extension? if yes, please provide url.

Comment: http://flysystem.thephpleague.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try function [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php).
According to example, your code should be looks something like this:

```
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately file_exists($file) returns false...if I do readfile($file) I get 'No such file or directory'